# Microsoft Sharepoint 2007 - Having limit of max absence (MC,Leave) function?

Tags: 2007, custom, custom-actions, sharepoint-calendar

I've just joined a company, and they threw me their sharepoint website which had functions up and running, including the Absence and Leave Calendar. Currently the absence and leave calendar functions works well, but I am not sure whether does Sharepoint itself actually includes the amount of max absences (MC,Leave, etc) status inside as well because as what I can see, the employee can apply as many leaves as he/she wants, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no specific "Absence and Leave Calendar" feature either in "Windows SharePoint Services", or in "Microsoft Office Sharepoint Sever" standard feature set. What you are talking is either:

- SharePoint standard calendar with some fields added and maybe some default approval workflow enabled. In this case, there should be no trouble with adding as many items per employee as needed;
- some third party feature for registering absence. In this case you should look at feature's documentation to find out the limits.